# WP multisite mobile header custom button added as anchor link in header.php how to set one for each site

Tags: html, wordpress

Currently this anchor link is added to my header.php file which adds a custom GET STARTED button to a mobile header.

`<a class="button_cta_mobile" href="<?php echo home_url() . '/subscribe/'; ?>">GET STARTED</a>`

It works great, but now that I've "upgraded" to a multilingual WP multisite, I need a unique anchor link for each site. Domain is the same all over, only with country subdirectories like /de /uk and so on. Basically different slugs and text languages.

So what I'm wondering is, if even possible, can I add more anchor links pointing at different directories from header.php, and somehow exclude or include them at each of my sites?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you can use the `if else` conditions, that will filter buttons display by url adress or part of it if you want( by `contains` method).

Exemple: ** UPDATE**

```
`<php? 
  $var = echo page_url();
  $strVal = strval($val);
  if ($strVal contains '/en/') {
    '<a class="button_cta_mobile" href="<?php echo home_url() . '/en/subscribe/'; ?>">GET STARTED</a>'
  } else {
    '<a class="button_cta_mobile" href="<?php echo home_url() . '/subscribe/'; ?>">GET STARTED</a>'
 } ?>`
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me an example for contains method too? I think that's going to be easier for me, as I i'll just have to put in the country subdir. I guess this JS should not be added to header.php? :p

Comment: done. See your code above. I have update it for `contains` method using. P.S. This is a php code, not JS. You can put it directly in the header.php

Comment: Thanks! Where exactly do I put in my anchor link to this?

Comment: @Eivindur I have updated the code above for you. Now it's a full version. You can simple change the part of the text (typically, it's a language code `en`, `de`, `ch`, etc) and replace it with` `/en/ ` ` in the `if` condition. In this way, you can easily solve the problem of using different dom elements on multilang pages.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I tried. I did a copy paste too, and the get started button shows and works fine. But the if /en/ which in my case is /no/, does not, and the button text with some of the code from  } else { shows in the header.

Comment: @Eivindur if you do not want to show your button inside the header - just directly replace this code with your button code in the <body> of the page, where it's located. No need to put this in the header

Comment: I need it in header. But it messed the header up. the piece of code I mentioned is actually visible for all visitors to see, right there in the physical header. So I guess there's something wrong, somewhere. It did add the 2nd anchor link button to my header, but I guess there is something about the '/en/subscribe' link that won't take